# qgis2web produced an error

Tags: postgis, qgis2web

I'm trying to export some PostGIS layers but getting these two errors when using the qgis2web plugin, seems to be memory related but is too many layers or too large an extent or something else? Also the plugin takes about 5 minutes to open:-

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/xxxxx.xxxxxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 101, in previewMap
>   MainDialog.previewOL3(self)
>   File "C:/Users/xxxxx.xxxxxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 234, in previewOL3
>   previewFile = writeOL(self.iface, layers, groups, popup, visible, json, cluster, labels, params, utils.tempFolder())
>   File "C:/Users/xxxxx.xxxxxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\olwriter.py", line 53, in writeOL
>   exportLayers(layers, folder, precision, optimize, usedFields)
>   File "C:/Users/xxxxx.xxxxxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\utils.py", line 92, in exportLayers
>   lines = f.readlines()
>   MemoryError

and this error:-

> MemoryError 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/xxxxx.xxxxxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 111, in saveMap
>       MainDialog.saveLeaf(self)
>     File "C:/Users/xxxxx.xxxxxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 257, in saveLeaf
>       outputFile = writeLeaflet(self.iface, folder, 600, 400, 1, layers, visible, "", cluster, "", "", "", labels, 0, 0, json, params, popup)
>     File "C:/Users/xxxxx.xxxxxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletWriter.py", line 89, in writeLeaflet
>       lines = f.readlines()
>   MemoryError

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen that error, and am sure that you are right that it relates to the complexity or size of your layers consuming a large amount of memory.

The plugin is slow to start up because it immediately builds a preview. You can comment this out. In the plugin file `maindialog.py`, at about line 56, place a `#` at the beginning of the line `self.previewMap()`.

Beyond that, some more information about your data would probably help us find out whether there is a way we can improve the plugin to handle issues associated with large amounts of data.

UPDATE

I've just committed a change to try to address this issue. Try downloading master from https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web, and see whether it solves it.

I believe you are bound to run into issues rendering large amounts of data in the browser, but it would be good to know whether this at least solves your specific issue.